# how to customize facebook products sharing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have a list of products, I want to make share button for every product, so the shared post can contain the product image and product name, I searched in facebook documents and found that I should use the open graph, so the sharing customization will be done by meta tags, I can't imagine how I will use meta tags for all my products, so anybody have an idea to reach what I am asking for?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this page: http://ogp.me/

Just make sure that every article page got the correct Open Graph Tags and use the permalink in the href-parameter of the Share Button. You MUST use a separate URL for each product...although, you can also just use that one page and add a get parameter in the URL.

Comment: my products are in the same page, they don't have any inner pages or sub-links, so it just an image for each product and a share button for each product too.

Comment: you MUST use a separate url for each product...although, you can also just use that one page and add a get parameter in the url.